# How to remove the first 3 characters of the names of multiple files?

Tags: cmd, file-rename

I have a several files (. Mp3) that has a prefix of two numbers and a space, eg:

01 Music.mp3, 02 TheBeatles.mp3, 03 RollingStones.mp3

I would like to know how to remove the first 3 characters of all files in the folder, so I would just keep all the names and numbers would be removed.

I want to do this using the cmd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it with [sed for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm)

```
dir /b /a-d | sed -r "s/.{3}(.*)/echo ren \"^&\" \"\1\"/e"
```

Remove `echo` to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

This uses a helper batch file called repl.bat from - http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3855

Launch this batch file and examine renfile.bat before running it.

```
@echo off
dir /b /a-d |repl "...(.*)" "ren \x22$&\x22 \x22$1\x22" x >renfile.bat
```